# dropzone.js with asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, dropzone.js

For some reason my code is not working. I don't get an error with badfile.jpg and regardless of the file, when I drop an image it just displays the image in the browser regardless of where it is dropped. I have not defined the button action yet. Any idea on why it's not working?

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MVCDropZone.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {   
        public IActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = environment;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(IFormFile file)
        {
            var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Dropzone simple example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/dropzone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .dropzone-container {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .dropzone-drop-area {
            background-color: lightcyan;
            border: dashed 3px grey;
            width: 450px;
            min-height: 150px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 6px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropzone-drop-area:hover {
            background-color: darkorange;
            border: dashed 3px black;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Dropzone.options.uploader = {
                paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
                maxFilesize: 2, // MB
                maxFiles: 1,
                clickable: true,
                acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
                uploadMultiple: false,
                createImageThumbnails: true,
                accept: function (file, done) {
                    if (file.name == "badfile.jpg") {
                        done("This is a bad file!");
                    }
                    else {
                        //Show a confirm alert and display the image on the page.
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    </script>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>File Drag & Drop Upload</h2>

        <div class="dropzone-container" id="dropzone">
            <form action="/Home/UploadFiles" id="uploader">
                <div id="dropzone-drop-area" class="dropzone-drop-area">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Files</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One suggestion, use browser dev tools to verify that the dropzone.js file is being downloaded from your local server rather than generating a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, except the missing class `dropzone` in your form.
Dropzone.js attaches itself to all elements with the `dropzone` class.

See: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage

So try to change your Form-Code to:

```
<form action="/Home/UploadFiles" id="uploader" class="dropzone">
    <div id="dropzone-drop-area" class="dropzone-drop-area">
    </div>
</form>
```